# Assigning a variable from SQL to Python

Tags: python, sql, cs50

I've managed to make this work except for the line `for i in int(num_rows["COUNT(*)"]):`

With this i get a  `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

I checked with `for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5]` it updates the table however i get another error:
`row_symbol = rows[i]["symbol"]`
IndexError: list index out of range ```

The main problem is, how do iterate over variable `rows` in the for loop?

```
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    user_id = session["user_id"]
    rows =db.execute("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id = :user_id ORDER BY symbol ASC", user_id=user_id)
    num_rows= db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM transactions WHERE id = :user_id ORDER BY symbol ASC", user_id=user_id)
    if not rows:
        return apology("You don't have any stocks, maybe buy some.")
    user= db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id = user_id)
    cash = user[0]["cash"]

    grand_total = cash

    for i in int(num_rows["COUNT(*)"]):
        row_symbol = rows[i]["symbol"]
        for row_symbol in rows:

            symbol=lookup(rows[i]["symbol"])
            price = symbol["price"]
            shares = rows[i]["shares"]
            total= shares * price
            db.execute("UPDATE transactions SET price = :price, Total=:total WHERE id=:user_id AND symbol=:symbol",
                       price=usd(price), total=total, user_id=user_id, symbol=rows[i]["symbol"])
            grand_total += cash
            if i ==5:
                return False




    return render_template("index.html", rows=rows,  cash = cash, total=grand_total)
```

Comment: You cannot iterate over an int: `for i in int(num_rows["COUNT(*)"])`

Comment: okay how do i iterate over ```rows``` and still assign the stock symbol in order to update the table?

Comment: Your code is a bit messy. You would better add fetch.all() at the end of your SQL queries and work directly on them. No need for extra queries for count(*) etc